Google Wallet Generic Card: Google Map Location and Website URL Not Displaying
I'm encountering an issue with the Google Wallet Generic Card where the Google Map location and website URL are not being displayed. I have verified that the data is correctly inputted into the card, but it still does not appear as expected.
  if ($passData->locations) {

            foreach ($passData->locations as $key => $location) {
                if ($location->status) {
                    $latitude = $location->latitude;
                    $longitude = $location->longitude;
                    $googleMapsUrl = "http://maps.google.com/?q={$latitude},{$longitude}";
                    $links[] = new Uri([
                        'uri' => $googleMapsUrl,
                        'description' => $location->description,
                        'id' => 'map_' . $key
                    ]);
                }
            }
        }

`  if ($passData->locations) {
        foreach ($passData->locations as $key => $location) {
            if ($location->status) {
                $latitude = $location->latitude;
                $longitude = $location->longitude;
                $googleMapsUrl = "http://maps.google.com/?q={$latitude},{$longitude}";
                $links[] = new Uri([
                    'uri' => $googleMapsUrl,
                    'description' => $location->description,
                    'id' => 'map_' . $key
                ]);
            }
        }
    }`


Not sure if you may have the same issue, but we had an error in a deprecated function. (related to map marker)
